# What does a CSS selector in square brackets select in HTML?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have seen this CSS rule-set in a library:

```
[text-uppercase] {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and I am not sure on how to use it in a `div`

```
<div class="text-uppercase | [text-uppercase]"></div>
```

I have tried both, but neither are working. I am seeing this in ionic2.

Comment: Go through this link for more information [http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the selector to work:
`<div text-uppercase></div>`

`[text-uppercase]` selector matches an attribute on a tag.

Answer (score 14):

It's not a class, you encountered a so called **[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)**.
It matches every html element that has got that attribute set, whatever the value. I.e. `<section text-uppercase="true">`, `<div text-uppercase="something">`, `<nav text-uppercase>`…

Look at the reference provided on the link above for more advanced usage scenarios.

```css
[text-uppercase] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span text-uppercase>hello</span>
```