# CSS selector with nesting square brackets react

Tags: css, reactjs

I came across a CSS selector with nesting square brackets like this in a library. Tried to search and understand what does it mean, but can't find any information. Can anyone explain it:

```css
[['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']]: {
    // CSS props here
}
```

Edit: it's in the `style` props of GlobalTheme component from emotion lib, the project using React.

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895301/what-does-a-css-selector-in-square-brackets-select-in-html) is similar to your question.

Comment: Doesn't look like CSS to me, so this is probably some preprocessor syntax, I suppose.

Comment: @CBroe Oh, lemme edit a bit it's in the `style` props of emotion library and the project is React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled) it is mostly used to style components.

Example from the documentation :

```
  import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const Child = styled.div({
  color: 'red'
})

const Parent = styled.div({
  [Child]: {
    color: 'green'
  }
})

render(
  <div>
    <Parent>
      <Child>green</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Child>red</Child>
  </div>
)
```